# Restrict Azure AD Application to specific storage resource

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-storage

I'm creating a new internal user-delegated Azure AD Application to read from a specific Azure Storage container.

Any users who login to this application should be granted access to this application.

If I use the scope: `https://storage.azure.com/user_impersonation` then the Access Token can work for **all** Azure Storage accounts in my tenant.

If I use the scope: `https://<my_storage_account>.blob.core.windows.net/user_impersonation` then the token only works with my specific account.

But, this scope restriction is being added during auth stage in a web app and can be spoofed.

Some of my users naturally have higher privilege and I don't want these access tokens being abused.

Is it possible to configure the app to restrict the tokens so they can only be used for specific resources?

A similar concept would be when I grant access for an app to view my GitHub repos, I can restrict with repos the app is allowed to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can [scope access given to a principal (user or application) to Azure Storage resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#resource-scope). Permissions are given trough [Azure Storage RBAC roles assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal). Without them the principal won't be able to do anything.